# Wordpress add class to menu work working with my theme

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am using a WordPress theme called 'Wordpress Foundation v2 by 320press'

I am using the custom menus within the WordPress dashboard, I want to add a class to the 'li' to change the styles of the sub menus:

For Example:
About Us -  will have a sub menu of four sublinks, therefore i want to add a class to that submemu called .fourNav which will then set each 'li' a with of 25%.

Then Customers - will have 2 sub links, so i want to add a class called .twoNav to each 'li' which will have a width of 50%.

I also want to add another class on top of these for each 'li' that will have a background image to each 'li'.

The Wordpress menu allows you to add classes and a description which will be displayed in the menu, but when i inspect the element the classes are not getting applied.

However when i add the class manually within the DOM it picks up the CSS and works.

How can i add the menu system to its full ability within this theme?

This is what im doing, but its not adding the class on:

http://thesis-blogs.com/add-a-custom-class-to-each-item-in-the-wordpress-menu/

So what i think i need is a snippet of php to allow the menu system to work with my theme. As when i add in the class in the dashboard my theme doesnt apply it.

This is the code that gets outputting in the html: -

```
<ul id="menu-main-nav" class="top-nav nav-bar hide-for-small">
 <li id="menu-item-5" class="has-flyout active">
 <a href="page link here">Home</a><a href="#" class="flyout-toggle"></a>
  <ul class="flyout" style="display: none;">
   <li id="menu-item-50"><a href="page link here">sub menu four</a></li>
   <li id="menu-item-51"><a href="page link here">sub menu three</a></li>
   <li id="menu-item-52"><a href="page link here">sub menu two</a></li>
   <li id="menu-item-53"><a href="page link here">sub menu one</a></li>
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you post your html structure too

Answer (score 0):

you have to edit the template code directly...

i think the menú is in

```
worpressdir/wp-content/themes/yourthemename/header.php
```

in order to edit this correctly you will need a medium skills with PHP and html. good luck

Answer (score 0):

Go to Appearance -> Menus -> Screen options - then the following
[image: hope this is helpful =)]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood from your requirements this is how it should work:
1. When you hover over a menu item, it should get a new class name.
2. When you hover over a sub-menu item, both the sub-menu item and the parent element of the corresponding sub-menu item should get a new class name.

If this is what you want checkout this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/39james/LgMdT/2/). I have used jquery for this. Check if this helps you.

HTML:

```
<ul class="menu-bar">
    <li class="menu-block">Menu 1</li>
    <li class="menu-block">Menu 2
        <ul class="sub-menu-block">
            <li class="sb-menu-list">Sub Menu</li>
            <li class="sb-menu-list">Sub Menu</li>
            <li class="sb-menu-list">Sub Menu</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-block">Menu 3</li>
    <li class="menu-block">Menu 4</li>
    <li class="menu-block">Menu 5</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.menu-bar{
    background-color:blue;
    width:100%;
    display:inline-block;
}

.menu-bar > li{
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;

}
.sub-menu-block{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    padding-left:0;
    width:75px;
    padding:10px 3px;
    background-color:#ccc;
}
.menu-bar > li:hover .sub-menu-block{
    display:block;
}
.sub-menu-block li{
    list-style: none;
    display:block;
    padding: 4px 0;
}
.sub-menu-block li:hover{
    background-color:red;
}
```

JQuery

```
$(function(){
    $(".menu-block").on("mouseover",function(){
        $(this).addClass('hovered');
    });
    $(".menu-block").on("mouseout",function(){
        $(this).removeClass('hovered');
    });
    $(".sb-menu-list").on("mouseover",function(){
        $(this).addClass('child-hovered');
        $(this).parents(".menu-block").addClass('parent-hovered');
    });
    $(".sb-menu-list").on("mouseout",function(){
        $(this).removeClass('child-hovered');
        $(this).parents(".menu-block").removeClass('parent-hovered');
    });
});
```

Comment: This is kind of it, but my issue is - in my WordPress dashboard > Menus, it allows you to add a class to the menu item. I add my class but its not picked up. My CSS works for what I need if I add in the class manually within the DOM. The issue is my theme possibly doesnt support the menu class option? So I need a snippet to get this working to allow me to add the class

Comment: @John your `nav-bar ul` will have a class name right? So in that case won't you be able to acquire what you want by replacing ".menu-block" in the JQuery with "your_navbar_class_name li" ?

Comment: Hi, i have added the code in the main post. As you can see there is no class being assigned to the li.